# Eidos Thief - how to rotate character?

Tags: thief

I just picked up Thief by Eidos again (the latest version).

Stupid quesstion, but how do I rotate? I can move forward/back/right/left, but can't seem to turn. How do I stand still and roatate?

Comment: What platform are you using? (eg if PC why does mouse not work?)

Comment: Windows 10, laptop with touchpad. I don't want ot use a mouse, if I can avoid it

Comment: If you're talking about the 2014 release of Thief, pretty sure it relies on [what we used to call] mouselook. You can't really play it without a mouse - does the touchpad rotate? Or are you using a controller or some sort?

Comment: Yup, it's the 2014 version (the lastest), bought through Steam, so it ought to be up to date. I am almost sure that Ised to play it laptop/touchpad only. However, I just checked & it works with a mouse, so I guess that I have to live with that. Thanks a 1,000,000 for your help

Comment: Does the touchpad not work in game?